# Как передать скрипту аргументы из тхт

Tags: python, python-3.x, cisco, cisco-ios

пишу скрипт на питоне в котором необходимо по очереди подключаться к разным коммутаторам из списка в тхт файле.В этом файле содержаться только ip адреса подключений ,а я хочу добавить в него логины и пароли от цисок,чтобы скрипт сразу конектился без участия пользователя.Пример строки в тхт файле-

> 192.168.1.2 : логинциски : парольциски : энейблпароль :портподключения

Вопрос в том как это реализовать.

```
import sys
import time
from netmiko import ConnectHandler
import os
import cmd
import datetime
import re
import shutil

now = datetime.datetime.now()
device_params={}
with open('ip2.txt', 'r') as f:
    nums = f.read().splitlines()
    for el in nums:
        if el:
            ip, user, password, enable_password, port, = el.replace(' ', '').split(":")
            device_params = {
                'device_type': 'cisco_ios_telnet',
                'ip': ip,
                'username': user,
                'password': password,
                'secret': enable_password,
                'port': port
            }
            print(device_params)
        try:
            connection = ConnectHandler(**device_params)
            connection.enable()
            output = connection.send_command('show run')
            prompt = connection.find_prompt()
            hostname = prompt[:-1]
            path = 'C:/adb/'
            folder_names = str(now.year) + '-' + str(now.month) + '-' + str(now.day)


            def createFolderForTiff(folder_names, path):
                _fold_name = folder_names
                _path = path

                if (os.path.exists(_path + '/' + _fold_name)):
                    print('Папка с именем ' + folder_names + ' уже существует')
                else:
                    os.chdir(_path)
                    os.mkdir(_fold_name)


            createFolderForTiff(folder_names, path)

            today = str(now.year) + '-' + str(now.month) + '-' + str(now.day)
            file = today + '-' + hostname + '.txt'
            with open(path + folder_names + '/' + file, 'w') as backup:
                backup.write(output)
                print('Backup of ' + hostname + ' completed successfuly')
                print('#' * 30)
            connection.disconnect()
        except ():
            device_type=device_params.setdefault('device_type','cisco_ios')
            connection = ConnectHandler(**device_params)
            connection.enable()
            output = connection.send_command('show run')
            prompt = connection.find_prompt()
            hostname = prompt[:-1]
            path = 'C:/adb/'
            folder_names = str(now.year) + '-' + str(now.month) + '-' + str(now.day)
            def createFolderForTiff(folder_names, path):
                _fold_name = folder_names
                _path = path

                if (os.path.exists(_path + '/' + _fold_name)):
                    print('Папка с именем ' + folder_names + ' уже существует')
                else:
                    os.chdir(_path)
                    os.mkdir(_fold_name)

            createFolderForTiff(folder_names, path)

            today = str(now.year) + '-' + str(now.month) + '-' + str(now.day)
            file = today + '-' + hostname + '.txt'
            with open (path+folder_names+'/'+file, 'w') as backup:
                backup.write(output)
                print('Backup of ' + hostname + ' completed successfuly')
                print('#' *30)
            connection.disconnect()
```

Comment: строка в текстовом файле должна быть именно такой?

Comment: Нет,это не принципиально,главное чтобы скрипт получал данные о подключении и все

Comment: Грубо говоря в файле должен быть пул адресов ,паролей ,портов, логинов, и енбпаролей.,чтобы скрипт мог без участия пользователя пробегаться по цискам и выполнять команды из скрипта,например бекап отправлял на тфтп

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если трудности именно с тем что не знаете как получить параметры из текстового файла

```
device_params={}
with open('text.txt', 'r') as f:
    nums = f.read().splitlines() 
    for el in nums:
        if el:
            ip, user, password, enable_password, port, = el.replace(' ', '').split(":")
            device_params = {
                'device_type': 'cisco_ios',
                'ip': ip,
                'username': user,
                'password': password,
                'secret': enable_password,
                'port': port
            }
            print(device_params)
```

в итоге получаем вывод

```
подключение к ip
192.168.1.2
вводим логин
admin
подключение к ip
192.168.1.3
вводим логин
admin
подключение к ip
192.168.1.4
вводим логин
admin
подключение к ip
192.168.1.5
вводим логин
admin
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ,я таким способом ip беру из файла,но у меня получается новая строка в этом файле это новый айпи новый логин и т.д. Т.е. скрипт циклично пролистывает весь список и сначала конектился к коммутатору в первой строке с его данными,потом к коммутатору во второй строке с его данными и т.д. А если я разбиваю файл тхт сплитом то у меня получится что следующий ip адрес уже будет [5] ,логин 6 и так далее по списку. Я не могу понять как мне тогда указать словарю откуда из тхт файла ему брать ip и другие данные.

Comment: @МихаилHollman все следующие ip адреса будут [0]. `f.read().splitlines()` разбивает файл на строки. В итоге вы получаете список строк. И потом уже циклом проходим по каждому элементу(строке) этого списка.

Comment: Спасибо,за разъяснение,попробую )

Comment: @МихаилHollman надеюсь поможет

Comment: Добавил код для наглядности ,через pycharm в режиме отладки показывается что переменные получают значения ,но нетмико не может понять мой словарь,где-то я  накосячил. Вроде бы разбил список построчно,получил элементы ,их записал в словарь,к словарю уже обращается нетмико ,но происходит необратимое исключение (

Comment: @МихаилHollman что за исключение? а как в итоге выглядит словарь? (выведите его принтом)

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/pyt/Backup Cisco RC3.py", line 14, in <module>
    ip, user, password, enable_password, port, = res[0]
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Словарь выводится так как и надо в принципе ip:192.168.*.* password:**** и т.д. но пайчарм указывает на строчку с res[0] и выдает ошибку о которой я выше написал

Comment: @МихаилHollman изменил код, попробуйте так заносить в словарь , в консоли не вижу никаких ошибок у себя

Comment: ip, user, password, enable_password, port, = el.replace(' ', '').split(":")
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 5, got 1)

Comment: не понимаю,в дебаггере все ровно,значения получаются,в словарь записываются,откуда ошибка,почему получено одно из пяти?

Comment: @МихаилHollman проблема в вашем файле скорее всего , когда я добавил в последнюю строку что либо получаю такую же ошибку. Перепроверьте файл. А лучше сделайте его в формате csv `192.168.1.2;admin;admin;admin;8000`

Comment: @МихаилHollman еще проблема может быть в том что у вас после последнего набора данных стоит пустые строки(т.е enter)  поправил код в ответе , попробуйте

Comment: Ошибки больше нет,спасибо вам!)Все работает, на данный момент бекап летит не в то место где создает папку,как решу эту проблему ,выложу исходный код здесь . Еще раз спасибо за помощь!)

Comment: @МихаилHollman не за что)

Comment: Код сверху актуальный добавил.